# Exceptions in a thread are written to System.err instead of getting caught

Tags: java, android, exception

I've seen it happen a few times already but I can't seem to find any mention for this. In this case I'm doing network operations and upon not resolving a host the worker thread dies and logcat shows the following:

```
Warning System.err  8/14/2011 8:41:58 PM    4355    java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "q": No address associated with hostname
Warning System.err  8/14/2011 8:41:58 PM    4355    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:496)
Warning System.err  8/14/2011 8:41:58 PM    4355    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:277)
Warning System.err  8/14/2011 8:41:58 PM    4355    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:249)
Warning System.err  8/14/2011 8:41:58 PM    4355    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
Warning System.err  8/14/2011 8:41:58 PM    4355    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
Warning System.err  8/14/2011 8:41:58 PM    4355    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
Warning System.err  8/14/2011 8:41:58 PM    4355    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
Warning System.err  8/14/2011 8:41:58 PM    4355    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
Warning System.err  8/14/2011 8:41:58 PM    4355    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
...
Warning dalvikvm    8/14/2011 8:41:58 PM    4355    threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4013a760)
```

As you see the exception is written to the System.err stream (which is Java's stderr that Android doesn't actually use or supports). It's not caught by anything:

1. try catch statements don't work since this is in a thread opened by
   the line try expected.
2. `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CustomExceptionHandler())` doesn't work too, which just seems very wrong.

So my questions are:

1. Why do some exceptions behave differently than others on a *system* level (aka they bypass `Thread.setDefault`)?
2. How do I still get these exceptions without resorting to reading System.err or other "hacky" solutions?

Edit:
Android 3.1, Samsung Tab 10.1, but I'm pretty sure this isn't a device or OS dependent issue.

Comment: Are you using an ExecutorService?

Comment: @mibollma first time I hear about that, so no. Unless of course something down the stack from me uses it.

Comment: What is the code that you are using?  The stack trace you've provided is happening on another thread, so it's possible that there is a different exception that you might be able to catch.

Comment: @mibollma Actually now that I'm stepping into a library I'm using I see that they do use ThreadPoolExecutor which is apparently a type of ExecutorService. Does that change something?

Comment: I just remembered that ExecutorService seems to set it's own uncaught exception handler and swallows any uncaught exceptions that occur inside it's threads. It's kinda annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Exception comes from commons-http - which is separate apache project just used by android. It uses own thread pools, so your setting has no effect on those threads.
2. If commons-http swallows them and logs to system.err,  you can not

Comment: I know the Apache code is separate but I thought they were at least somehow integrated with the Android platform conventions. Does that mean there is no way of using Apache code with the standard Android exception system?

Comment: Exception system has nothing to do with android - it is all java. Android java stack contains some 50% (my vague perception) of foreign java libraries. And commons-http client is pretty advanced piece of code, with full can of own worms -  maybe you just have to look for another exception?

Comment: I really don't want to accept your answer, because that means that I accept the reality that this thing is very broken. But I guess I'll have to eventually if noone gives me a better answer. Now I'm stuck with replacing stderr with a stream and trying to RE match the exception line from it. :(

Comment: What exactly you try to achieve? There is surely better way than replacing stderrr and parsing its contents

Comment: I'm trying to get the above exception and show it to the user / handle it in my code. Instead I get a NullPointerException on the next line of code since the above failed silently.

Comment: Maybe we should commit a new issue to android

Answer (score 0):

Just to have this for you future people:
Some library code under me was actually swallowing exceptions and writing the to system.err. I only just got the source code to the library, so I guess it's my fault for asking this, but I think Konstantin's answer is still important because of the thread pool answer.

Comment: I'd say it's the library author's fault for doing that, or at least for doing it without documenting it.